# Asymptotic analysis of $\int_0^{\infty}f(x)\cos(nx)dx$, as $n\to \infty$ where $f$ is a decaying-to-zero integrable function

Tags: integration, oscillatory-integral

This may be recognised as the real part of a certain Fourier transform, which in turn is known to $\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$, by the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma.

From here i am interested in the main asymptotic behaviour for large $n$. However, I have not been able to make a good guess on how the base function $f$ effects the asymptotics.

For example, if $f(x)=e^{-ax}$ for $a>0$, then
$\int_0^{\infty}f(x)\cos(nx)dx=\frac{a}{a^2+n^2}=O(n^{-2})$, for $n\to \infty$.

In addition, for the case $f(x)=e^{-ax^b}$, where $a,b>0$, we may use Mellins inversion formula and the residue theorem to find that $\int_0^{\infty}f(x)\cos(nx)dx=O(n^{-1-b})$.

I welcome any suggestions for any other special cases (e.g. $e^{-e^x}$ which is not solvable by the above methods ) or other general properties of the fourier transform.

Comment: That is the Riemann_Lebesgue Lemma and that limit is zeros I will be suprise if this is not a duplicate

Comment: I state that this goes to zero in the first sentence. I am interested in more detail i.e. the rate of decay. This is shown to vary depending on the choice of function.

Comment: The speed of convergence depends on how much $f(|x|)$ is regular at the origin.

Comment: How do you quantify regular? What happens, supposing $f$ is smooth everywhere?

Comment: If $f(|x|)$ is a function of class $C^k$ on the real line we may expect a decay of the Fourier coefficients of the $\frac{1}{n^{k+1}}$ kind, essentially. The Fourier cosine transform of $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ has an exponential decay.

Comment: Could you point me to a good reference on these topics? I would like to see, in a little more detail, the effect of regularity on the speed of decay. Thank you!

Comment: A book: https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=-CCsBAAAQBAJ

Comment: @user385459: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series#Magnitude_of_Fourier_coefficients

Comment: Also, "method of stationary phase" (and in many cases, a steepest descent calculation in the complex plane gives higher order terms for the asymptotic series, which stationary phase doesn't).